# Trouble with Sitecore Linq to Solr and parentheses

Tags: solr

I have a Sitecore 8.1 / Solr 4.10 solution.  I am noticing that with a complex Linq query that includes a lot of parentheses that sometimes Solr returns no results.  But if I remove the parentheses and submit the query to Solr manually then the query works.

Here is the original query from the Sitecore Search.log file:

```
8124 12:12:30 INFO  Serialized Query - ?q=*:*&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=(((read_roles_sm:(extranet_anonymous_role) AND -denied_roles_sm:(extranet_anonymous_role)) AND (_path:(f0a12cf0ac2840619048797a1b893e00) AND (-_templatename:(*folder*) AND (((-sanitizedpath_s:(*_safety_data_sheets*) AND -sanitizedpath_s:(*_msds_files*)) AND -sanitizedpath_s:(*_some_new_path*)) AND -sanitizedpath_s:(*_f\(x\)*))))) AND _language:(en))&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
```

That query returns no results.  But if I remove the parentheses and submit this query it works.

```
/select?q=*:*&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=read_roles_sm:(extranet_anonymous_role)%20AND%20-denied_roles_sm:(extranet_anonymous_role)%20AND%20_path:(f0a12cf0ac2840619048797a1b893e00)%20AND%20-_templatename:(*folder*)%20AND%20-sanitizedpath_s:(*_safety_data_sheets*)%20AND%20-sanitizedpath_s:(*_msds_files*)%20AND%20-sanitizedpath_s:(*_some_new_path*)%20AND%20-sanitizedpath_s:(*_f\(x\)*)%20AND%20_language:(en)&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue I was having here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/multilist-with-search-field-does-not-return-search-results-with-two-or-more-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458086/how-do-i-control-the-priority-of-nested-queries-in-sitecore-contentsearch-with-t -- we were given a support binary, reference #398622 that will most likely resolve this issue for you as well. I would contact Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks Justin - looking at the Stackoverflow question you linked to fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the Sitecore Support binary #398622 as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458086/how-do-i-control-the-priority-of-nested-queries-in-sitecore-contentsearch-with-t. Once I did that the problems went away.