# Content Search Functionality Not Working

Tags: content-search, lucene

I am working on a search functionality to return items with certain template, location of the folder to look for in, and has the item name:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(GetSiteIndexName()).CreateSearchContext())
{
    ID recruitersBioBlocksFolderId = new ID(EmbraceGuids.RecruitersBioBlocksFolderId);
    ID recruiterTemplateId = new ID(EmbraceGuids.RecruiterContentBlockTemplateID);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recruiter))
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(x => x.TemplateId == recruiterTemplateId);
        predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Paths.Contains(recruitersBioBlocksFolderId));
        predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Name.Contains(recruiter));
    }

    var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate);
```

It was working fine before adding the last predicate:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Name.Contains(recruiter));
```

However, when I add the previous predicate to search for the item name with string i pass to this function, it doesn't work.

Any idea why isn't it working?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"? Do you get no results? Can you check the search query in the logs and test it with Luke on your index to see whether there should be any result for that query?

Comment: Yes if I add this predicate to search for the item name, it doesn't return any results, but if I remove this predicate and keep the rest, it returns results.

Comment: Check the search log for the query that is performed and test that on your index with Luke.

Comment: Could you show us how the Name field is defined in the C# model class? Also, please include your field configuration (the .config file).

Comment: It is the one used in the Default SearchResultItem, which is the following property: [IndexField("_name")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

Comment: Do you have `<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>` in your index configuration? If it's set to `false`, then the `_name` field will not be indexed. You need to use Luke to see if the field exists in the index.

Comment: It is set to true...From Where can I install Luke?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on? Have you tried querying something else besides `Name`, but keeping the number predicates the same? You might be having the same problem here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/trouble-with-sitecore-linq-to-solr-and-parentheses#comment3471_2337 -- you'll need to check your search log.

Comment: I am on Sitecore 8.1 Upadte 2, and yes i have other functions that have more than 3 predicates and it is working fine.. And the function above is returning results when I remove this specific name predicate.. Not sure why

Comment: You can download Luke tool from https://luke.googlecode.com/files/lukeall-3.5.0.jar. To run it, type "java -jar lukeall-3.5.0.jar". Check [this page](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/laurent-poulain-blog/2015/10/12/troubleshooting-lucene-search-issues) for troubleshooting Lucene search issues. Also look for the search query executed from search.log.xxxx.txt file under data/logs folder.

Comment: I tried your example in a sandbox and I get the expected results with a Name predicate. For example, I made 3 items: Joe, Bob, Bob Smith. When I search with the path and template predicates, and add x.Name.Contains("Bob"), I see Bob and Bob Smith in the results.  "Bob Smith" in the name predicate returns just Bob Smith. What value is in your "recruiter" variable?

Comment: The value in the recruiter value is "A" only

Comment: Abandoned by OP. Question lacks sufficient detail. Debugging.